# Return Nth Percentile row value of a column that is an aggregate value

Tags: sql, sql-server

*Related to SQL-Server*

I need to return the value for a column in the Nth percentile associated to multiple unique IDs in another column.  For example, for the dataset below, I need the value in the 80th Percentile in COL B for each unique value in COL A:

```
COL A       COL B
---------   --------
A           2
A           4
A           6
A           8
A           10
B           2
B           2   
B           3
B           5   
B           7
B           8
B           11  
B           13
B           17
B           18
```

The desired output would be:

```
COL A       COL B
--------    --------
A           8
B           13
```

This is based on the logic that:

> the 80th Percentile value for COL B is the 4th row value of 8 for value A in COL A;
>
> and that the 80th Percentile value for COL B is the 8th row value of 13 for value B in COL A

Comment: But what query have you tried?

Comment: Is this the exact table you're using at all times?

Comment: This is the sole table I'll need to use to get what the value in the 80th Percentile.  I'd join to COL A also to get more detailed info on the unique value (i.e. A or B) but that shouldn't impact this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the absolutely wretched query:

```
select r.t1, MIN(r.t2) FROM (SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT t1, t2 FROM tempTable where t1 = 'A' ORDER BY t2 desc ) as r
group by r.t1
union
SELECT s.t1, MIN(s.t2) FROM ( SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT t1, t2 FROM tempTable ORDER BY t2 DESC ) as s 
group by s.t1
```

Where t1 is Col A, t2 is Col B, and tempTable is your table.
This is solely based on your table provided and is by no means generic.

---

**EDIT:** I figured out how to apply it to the OP's question by using `ntile`

```
SELECT colA, colB,
        NTILE(5) OVER(PARTITION BY colA ORDER BY colB DESC) AS  'tileN'
FROM tempTable t
group by colA, colB ) as n
where n.tileN = 2
```

**What it does:**

NTile basically creates partitions of `100 / a` where a is `NTILE(a)`. By dividing by 5 we get partitions of 20 percent. Therefore 2 is the 80th percentile. Then we select the top 20 percent from that query to eliminate values that would be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this.  Unfortunately, my example is just a small sample size of the dataset I'm working with.  In my actual dataset, there will be a non-fixed amount of unique values in Col A.  (there will be approx. 200 unique values)

Comment: I can get the last unique value. I'm not sure how to compare only the individual unique col A's

Answer (score 0):

If you're on SQL 2012 or greater, you can use `percentile_disc()`

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        ('A', 2  ),
        ('A', 4  ),
        ('A', 6  ),
        ('A', 8  ),
        ('A', 10 ),
        ('B', 2  ),
        ('B', 2  ), 
        ('B', 3  ),
        ('B', 5  ), 
        ('B', 7  ),
        ('B', 8  ),
        ('B', 11 ), 
        ('B', 13 ),
        ('B', 17 ),
        ('B', 18 )
    ) AS x(a, v)
)
SELECT DISTINCT a
    , PERCENTILE_DISC(0.8) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v) OVER (PARTITION BY a)
FROM cte
```

Comment: OP has a dataset much larger than those values as written in comment to my answer. This will only work if he would type in each value manually?

Comment: No. The CTE was my way of materializing the test data. The meat of the answer is in the query. Substitute your actual data table for the cte and it will work just as well.

Comment: OUTSTANDING!! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for.  Thank you so much for this and for all who took the time to help!

Comment: Here at StackOverflow, we show our thanks by upvoting and accepting answers. Hit the little up arrow and checkbox next to my answer for that! ;)

Comment: @BenThul Unfortunately since I've only recently registered, I do not have a reputation of over 15 and therefore StackOverflow will not allow my upvote to reflect publicly.  I tried to Upvote as soon as I realized this is exactly what I needed.  Once, I do get my reputation over the minimum I promise to come back and upvote

Comment: Ha! No worries dude... it's all imaginary internet points to me. Welcome to SO!